# Footer: Sitemap side by side

Tags: html, css, footer, sitemap

I have a question about my sitemap if you look at the code you see ul and li. But every UL is below the other and i want it to be side by side. Every new UL side by side. How doe i do this? Working with first-child? ( the sitemap is inside my )

## Sitemap

```
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Opleiding</li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Visie & Beleid</li>
                                            <li>Opbouw Studieprogramma</li>
                                            <li>Competenties</li>
                                            <li>Diploma</li>
                                            <li>Beroepen</li>
                                        </ul>

                                    <li>Onderwijsprogramma</li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Mededelingen</li>
                                            <li>Uitagenda</li>
                                            <li>Propedeuse</li>
                                            <li>Verdieping 1</li>
                                            <li>Verdieping 2</li>
                                            <li>Afstuderen</li>
                                        </ul>

                                    <li>Organisatie</li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Contact</li>
                                            <li>Blog</li>
                                            <li>Docenten</li>
                                            <li>Onderwijsbureau</li>
                                            <li>Stagebureau</li>
                                            <li>Buitenlandbureau</li>
                                            <li>Examencommissie</li>
                                            <li>Decaan</li>
                                        </ul>

                                    <li>Stages en Projecten</li>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Stages</li>
                                            <li>Projecten</li>
                                        </ul>
                                </ul>
```

This is my CSS

```
footer{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 317%;
left: -10%;
background: lightgrey;
margin:10%;
padding: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try display inline-block or float left on the ul's you want side by side. I recommend adding classes to make the styling easier

HTML:

```
<ul>
                                <li>Opleiding</li>
                                    <ul class="sitemap">
                                        <li>Visie & Beleid</li>
                                        <li>Opbouw Studieprogramma</li>
                                        <li>Competenties</li>
                                        <li>Diploma</li>
                                        <li>Beroepen</li>
                                    </ul>

                                <li>Onderwijsprogramma</li>
                                    <ul class="sitemap">
                                        <li>Mededelingen</li>
                                        <li>Uitagenda</li>
                                        <li>Propedeuse</li>
                                        <li>Verdieping 1</li>
                                        <li>Verdieping 2</li>
                                        <li>Afstuderen</li>
                                    </ul>

                                <li>Organisatie</li>
                                    <ul class="sitemap">
                                        <li>Contact</li>
                                        <li>Blog</li>
                                        <li>Docenten</li>
                                        <li>Onderwijsbureau</li>
                                        <li>Stagebureau</li>
                                        <li>Buitenlandbureau</li>
                                        <li>Examencommissie</li>
                                        <li>Decaan</li>
                                    </ul>

                                <li>Stages en Projecten</li>
                                    <ul class="sitemap">
                                        <li>Stages</li>
                                        <li>Projecten</li>
                                    </ul>
                            </ul>
```

CSS:

```
footer .sitemap {
display: inline-block;
OR
float: left;
}
```

Comment: I would use inline-block, but if you do decide to float them, just make sure that you clear your floats.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the main thing is that i want to do it without using div or class? any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to do it without classes, then just apply his above CSS to you ul elements, but I would not recommend to do it without classes, as it will apply that style to every ul element in your site.

Comment: Maybe with nth-of-child or first-child?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters your markup is invald. If you want to nest ULs inside of another UL, it needs to be inside of an LI

```
<ul>
    <li>Title
          <ul>
              <li>Sub-Title</li>
          </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

From there, you probably just need something like this:

```
footer > ul > li {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fTCY5/